# javascript not a constructor

Tags: javascript, oop, require

I am trying to create a Javascript object, But it gives fatal of not a constructor object. What is wrong in the code.

```
form = new Form(data,option);
str = form.JsonToHTML();
```

And Below is the method,

```
 define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'router/router'
  ], function($, _, Backbone, Router) {

   var form = function(data, options) {
       this.data  = data;
       this.options = options,
       this.JsonToHtml = function() {
            alert(Backbone);
            alert(this.data);
    }
};

return form; 
});
```

Comment: `Form` is not defined.

Comment: I think you may have mis-copied some code. For example, it looks like you have a extra `});` at the end of your code there

Comment: you are in some trouble due to someone else's troubles!! Check from wherever u pasted :)

Comment: Thanks lot. It's a problem while calling the method. It's working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are not loading the `form` module correctly. You should be loading it like this:

```
define(['form'], function(Form) {
    var form = new Form(data,option);
    var str = form.JsonToHTML();
    //your code
});
```

The `form` module you're using is an [AMD module](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html). The way those work is that you create a local variable (function parameter) to reference each module your code depends on. In this case, you want to refer to the form constructor as `Form` so that `new Form` will work, which is why I called the function parameter `Form` in the above example.

I'm not sure whether the `form` module is one you wrote or written by someone else, but if you can change it, it would be a good idea to rename the function to `Form` (with an uppercase F) there also, for consistency and because it's a standard convention in JS that constructor functions start with an uppercase letter.

I suggest writing the `form` module like this:

```
 define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'router/router'
  ],
  function($, _, Backbone, Router) {

   function Form(data, options) {
       this.data  = data;
       this.options = options;
    }

    Form.prototype.jsonToHtml = function() {
        alert(Backbone);
        alert(this.data);
    }

    return Form; 
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I made a mistake while invoking as you suggested. It's working fine

Comment: I posted how I would write it...using the `prototype` isn't necessary but is the standard approach for OO in JS (and is slightly more memory efficient).  Note that generally speaking the prototype should only contain methods, not properties (since you want methods to be shared by all instances, but each instance has different property values). Also I noticed a typo while doing this...you had a comma instead of a semicolon in one spot; maybe that was your main problem.

Comment: YW. If you found this answer helpful, please mark it as the accepted answer when you get a chance; thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined a function called Form, you can however simulate this by creating an empty object and calling your form function with the `call` method.

I.e.

```
var form = {};
formFunc.call(form, data, option);
form.JsonToHtml(); // will work
```

Comment: There actually is a form constructor here (in an AMD module), it just wasn't loaded correctly.